How do I get CAN2.0 messages to get read by a controller that is CANopen?
I have a Curtis 1238 controller and lithium ion battery bank. I am trying to get the Curtis controller to take state of charge from the BMS in the lithium battery bank over CAN bus. The Curtis controller is CANopen and the BMS is CAN2.0. What is the best way to achieve this?

From what I understand the 1238 Curtis Controller has a generic CAN bus connection and isn't only CANopen specific. CAN specifies the physical and data link layers. CANopen the layers up to the application layer. Anything that supports CAN also works with CANopen.

You need to study how CAN works as well of the OSI model. Saying something like "controller is CANopen and the BMS is CAN2.0" is like saying "One animal is a German Shepherd and a the other animal is a dog". CANopen is the application layer and CAN2.0 is the physical + datalink layer. So it is senseless to compare them. CANopen is very likely using "CAN2.0" (or more correctly high speed CAN, ISO 11898-2). If you don't even know these basics, there is no hope to succeed with this project.

Thanks velvet and Lundin for your replies and clarification. I am new to this and trying to wrap my head around how it works,how to make it work or who to hire.
